# ParseInt Exception

Tags: android, runtime

I am creating a small calc app with EditText views and Im running into an runtime exception when the user leaves an EditText view empty causing the ParseInt to try and Parse nothing. Ive read that I need to 'Try' and 'Catch' this error before it occurs, but Im unsure of where and how to do this!

Any advice is much appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
public class HandlerExamples extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.testButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

public void onClick(View v) {
            String a,b,t;
            double vis;

            EditText txtbox1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.A);
                EditText txtbox2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.B);
                EditText txtbox3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.t);
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Answer);

            a = txtbox1.getText().toString();
            b = txtbox2.getText().toString();
            t = txtbox3.getText().toString();

            vis = ((Integer.parseInt(a)*1) + (Integer.parseInt(b)*2)) / (Double.parseDouble(t));
            tv.setText(double.toString(vis));       
    }
}
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    switch(id){
    case R.id.xx:
        //do things xx click
        break;
    case R.id.yy:
        //do things yy click
        break;
    }
}
```

you can get the view id to know whick widget was clicked.

Comment: I found that Im running into a ParseInteger issue and that is what is causing the error at runtime. I have edited the question appropriately. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Changwei Yao defined one way you can do this, but here's the way most Android programmers would do this (programmatically), since it's a little easier to read and figure out what your widgets are doing:

But first, remove the `implements OnClickListener` from your Activity, as it's not needed.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // what you want your button to do when clicked
    }
}
editText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // what you want your EditText to do when clicked
        // (such as editText.setText(""))
    }
}
```

Another way to do the same thing is to define `android:onClick="insert_method_name_here"` for the widgets that you want perform an action when clicked. In your case, in your main.xml (since that's what you're using in your Activity), you could write something like...

```
<Button android:id="@+id/testButton"
    (other attributes you wish to apply to the button)
    android:onClick="buttonAction" />
<EditText
    (other attributes)
    android:onClick="textAction" />
```

And then, in your Activity, you define the methods `buttonAction(View v)` and `textAction(View v)`. Note that these methods must be `public void`, and must take the sole argument `View v`.

(One advantage of the XML method is that you don't necessarily have to define an `android:id` attribute for these widgets, unless you need to be able to manipulate them or extract information from them in your code (which means you will need to define an `android:id` for your `EditText` since you'll likely want the user's input))

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to exclude the empty text field then hotveryspicy's solution is probably the quickest. For a secure solution: catching the NumberFormatException will filter anything that can not be converted to an integer.

```
int vis;
try {
    vis = Integer.parseInt(a);
}
catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
    Log.e(TAG,"trying to convert:"+a+" to integer failed");
    vis = 0;
}
```